# Date coming with "00/01/1900"

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

We have some scheduler processes that do some processing and insert records into multiple tables.
For some records, the insert date stored is having "00/01/1900 00:13:00.634588 +00:13" as the value instead of the time that the request was processed.

I have raised with my DBA and he said i should check the application. The scheduler processes are CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and SYSDATE to insert into our tables.

Some of the tables that uses trigger are having same issue as well.
Also, this is not happening all the time.

Can you suggest what i need to do or check and it is currently causing a lot of data inconsistent issues with transaction reporting.

Below is the trigger statement.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CB_SCHEDULES_UPD_TRIG   
   BEFORE UPDATE ON CB_SCHEDULES
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN

   :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_D := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

END;
```

the LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_D column is defined as TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE with default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Perhaps you should post that piece of code that insert date values.

Comment: Dates don't have fractional seconds or a time zone.  Do you actually have a `timestamp with time zone` column (or `with local time zone`)?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CB_SCHEDULES_UPD_TRIG  
BEFORE UPDATE ON CB_SCHEDULES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_D := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

END;

Comment: thats the code for the trigger statement

Comment: Please edit your question to add formatted code, don't put it in comments. Can you also please clarify the data type of the columns - what data type is `last_modified_date_d`? If that is a string - which it shouldn't be - then the NLS and time zone settings for the session that performs the insert might be useful too.

Comment: I have edited the question and have formatted the code as well. The date type of the column is TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE with default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @IfeanyiAnthony Just commenting on your comment below: "_the insert statement is making current_timestamp and sysdate. The record is expected to have..._"  You know your trigger will not execute for an `INSERT` statement right?  For a record that was only inserted and never updated, the value of `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_D` will be whatever the user or application code provided.  Your `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger would not have fired.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible scenarios:

1. You have a valid `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` but the error is in formatting it for display.

   You can specify an explicit format model to check the data:

   ```sql
   SELECT TO_CHAR(your_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD')
            AS formatted_timestamp
   FROM   your_table;
   ```

   In this case you need to fix how your timestamp is being displayed (but you do not need to fix the data).
2. You have invalid data. A `TIMESTAMP` (and a `DATE`) is a binary data type and when third-party database drivers (such as JDBC, etc.) insert a `TIMESTAMP` in the correct binary format then no error checking is performed by the database (as it is assumed that any checks are carried out by that third-party and it is not required/desired to repeat the checks in the database). If this is the case and invalid data is inserted bypassing checks in the third-party application then there is nothing you can do other than:

   - Try to manually fix the erroneous values; and
   - Debug the third-party application and work out how it is putting the incorrect values in.

Comment: @IfeanyiAnthony What is the problem? That the year is `1900` (which is valid data but may not be what you expect) or that the day (or month, depending on your format model) is `00` (which is invalid data)? What is the output of `SELECT TO_CHAR(FROM_DATE_D, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD') AS format, DUMP(from_date_d) AS dmp FROM cb_account_service_list WHERE service_info_v=9162548693`?

Comment: I am still new to this, the output is '1900-01-00 00:13:00.634588 LMT' .The problem is that,the insert statement is making current_timestamp and sysdate. The record is expected to have the date time when it was inserted, instead, it is having '1900' as the year which is wrong.

Comment: @IfeanyiAnthony `1900` may be unexpected but its not invalid. `00` for the day is invalid as you cannot have a day `0` in a month and is actually the bigger issue in your data. Whatever the issue, **YOU** need to go through the process and work out where the data came from because whatever created that value has managed to create an `TIMESTAMP` where the day is `0` and has bypassed all the normal in-database checks. There is not enough information in the question for us to debug where it came from (the trigger in the question will not create an invalid timestamp where the day is `0`).